# Grails Object --> LinkedHashMap converter

Tags: grails, linkedhashmap

Like the JSON converter, is there any easy way to convert an object into LinkedHashMap. The JSON string is constructed as

```
   def query = new JSON(cmd).toString()
```

anything similar..

thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Grails, I could do it by object.parameters .. also, in my case I could use the params (request parameters)